# How do you add table column sort functionality to an EntityFieldQuery?

Tags: database

I have an EntityFieldQuery that gets displayed in a table. How do I add clickable sort-by-column functionality? When I use regular db_select queries I can sort using the following code:

```
 $query = db_select('tablename', 't')
   ->extend('PagerDefault')
   ->limit(50)
   ->extend('TableSort')

 // ...

 $query = $query->orderByHeader($header)
 $results = $query->execute();
```

Everything looks good and when the table is displayed I can click on the columns and they are hyperlinks and I can sort just fine. However, now that I have an EntityFieldQuery I can't seem to duplicate the functionality. This is what I have so far:

```
$header = array(
  'title' => array(
    'data' => t('Date'),
    'type' => 'field',
    'specifier' => array(
      'field' => 'field_articledate',
      'column' => 'value',
    ),
  ),
);
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1);

$query = $query->tableSort($header);
$query = $query->pager(100);

$results = $query->execute();
```

A one-column header appears and it says "Date" as expected, but it is not a clickable hyperlink. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Maybe it's getting confused between the array key (title), which is a node property, and the field specifier you've given. To test just try changing the array key to something else

Comment: I changed 'title' to 'something' and it did not fix the problem.

Comment: @MrSnrub : Did you find this solution. If yes then post it. i m also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this thread is a little old but adding 'field' to the array fixes the issue.

e.g.

```
$header = array(
  'title' => array(
    'data' => t('Date'),
    'type' => 'field',
    'specifier' => array(
      'field' => 'field_articledate',
      'column' => 'value',
    ),
    'field' => '', //There is an Isset call that prevents links from showing without this.
  ),
);
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1);

$query = $query->tableSort($header);
$query = $query->pager(100);

$results = $query->execute();
```

See: https://www.drupal.org/node/885014#comment-3464666 for a comment on the issue.